# Parameterize a Feature in Cucumber

Tags: javascript, cucumber, gherkin

I have a situation where I'm using the same set of parameters for every Scenario Outline in my test suite (I'm using javascript):

```
Feature: Select a Product
  Install Checklist for Product

  Scenario Outline: functionA() is called on page type <type> -- No errors
    Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
    Then I should see no errors are thrown

    Examples:
      | type |
      | "product" |
      | "home" |
      | "collection" |

  Scenario Outline: functionA() is called on page type <type> -- Minimal delay
    Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
    Then there is a minimal delay before calling functionA()

    Examples:
      | type |
      | "product" |
      | "home" |
      | "collection" |

  Scenario Outline: functionA() is called -- correct type <type>
    Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
    Then the page type is <type>

    Examples:
      | type |
      | "product" |
      | "home" |
      | "collection" |

  ...many more tests using an identical Examples array
```

I'm looking to improve the structure of this code and the best way I can see to do that would be to be able to put the `Examples` section outside of the individual `Scenario Outlines` as global params.  Essentially I'm looking to run each of these `Scenarios` with each of the entries in `Examples` without having to repeat the `Examples` array for each `Scenario`. I'm sure you can see that modifying the `Examples` array would be cumbersome in the future.

Is there a way to do this in Cucumber?

Something like:

```
Feature Outline: Select a Product
  Install Checklist for Product

  Scenario Outline: functionA() is called on page type <type> -- No errors
    Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
    Then I should see no errors are thrown

  Scenario Outline: functionA() is called on page type <type> -- Minimal delay
    Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
    Then there is a minimal delay before calling functionA()

  Scenario Outline: functionA() is called -- correct type <type>
    Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
    Then the page type is <type>

  ...many more tests using an identical Examples array

  Examples:
    | type |
    | "product" |
    | "home" |
    | "collection" |
```

or

```
Feature: Select a Product
  Install Checklist for Product

  Rule Outline: verify functionA() on page type <type>

    Scenario Outline: functionA() is called on page type <type> -- No errors
      Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
      Then I should see no errors are thrown

    Scenario Outline: functionA() is called on page type <type> -- Minimal delay
      Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
      Then there is a minimal delay before calling functionA()

    Scenario Outline: functionA() is called -- correct type <type>
      Given I load the site and go to a <type> page
      Then the page type is <type>

  ...many more tests using an identical Examples array

    Examples:
      | type |
      | "product" |
      | "home" |
      | "collection" |
```

Edit: For anyone looking at this in the future, I've opened a related issue here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/879

Comment: I am afraid that you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Think about what your scenarios describe. Read this blog post from Aslak Hellesøy, the creator of Cucumber, https://cucumber.io/blog/collaboration/the-worlds-most-misunderstood-collaboration-tool/

What you are trying to achieve is not something Cucumber is designed to solve.

Comment: I'd seen that, but I'm confused as to why test-step level and test-case level parameterization is considered "something Cucumber is designed to solve", but moving up to test-suite is suddenly "something Cucumber isn't designed to solve".  Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: I think one source for your confusion is your wording "moving up to test-suite". What you want would not be referred to as moving up by a lot of folks. It would be referred to as moving down by these folks.

Comment: The reasoning behind why this isn't a supported use can is that if you use cucumber as a scripting tool, and that is what you use as far as I can understand, then you would be better off with a proper scripting/testing tool. In the Java world that would be tools like JUnit.

Comment: The purpose with Cucumber and BDD is to be able to document a common understanding of a problem. The underlaying implementation is therefore uninteresting. The documentation happens to lend it self very well for execution. The documentation, shared knowledge and therefore communication is the goal for Cucumber. Not testing. Testing is a nice side effect, but nothing more.

Comment: This is the reason why parameterizing the tests isn't supported by Cucumber. If you allow people to misuse a tool, they will. It is therefore better to stop them and point them in other directions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) plugin which enables to reuse examples by using data provider. It is extension to gherkin with [BDD2 syntax](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd2.html)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.  It would have been amazing if it was available for javascript.  Do you know of any alternatives that work with javascript?

Comment: No, this plugin supports only Cucumber Java, i am not sure if similar plugin available for javascript.